# Having both chisq.test and fisher.test in a tbl_summary table

Tags: gtsummary

Is it possible to have a tbl_summary table with a "chisq.test" when expected cell counts >=5 and "fisher.test" when expected cell counts <5 without merging two separate tables? If so, how would script it?

Comment: what have you tried so far? can you share code and sample of your data?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the add_p() help file? This is the default behavior. Tests default to "kruskal.test" for continuous variables ("wilcox.test" when "by" variable has two levels), "chisq.test.no.correct" for categorical variables with all expected cell counts >=5, and "fisher.test" for categorical